# iOS: AVCaptureDevicePosition, how to get from SCRecorder (error: Bad receiver type)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera, avcapturedevice

I have some code, in objective-c, which is as follows:

```
@interface SCRecorderPViewController () {
    SCRecorder *_recorder;
    UIImage *_photo;
    SCRecordSession *_recordSession;
    UIImageView *_ghostImageView;
    CGFloat screenWidth;
    CGFloat screenHeight;

}
```

And I want to get the active device/camera (whether it is the front one, or the back one), as so:

```
AVCaptureDevicePosition position = [[_recorder device] position];
```

But I get an error: `Bad receiver type 'AVCaptureDevicePosition' (aka 'enum AVCaptureDevicePosition')`

What am I doing "wrong"?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
AVCaptureDevicePosition position = [_recorder device];
```

Notice that in the source file.

```
/**
 Change the current used device
 */

@property (assign, nonatomic) AVCaptureDevicePosition device;
```